# python execute factorial program using input function

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a factorial program its working well when i execute the full program in command line mode.
When i write the program in .py file and trying to execute and when i call the file  like

```
>> python factorial.py
```

I get error

```
def factorial(n):
    if n==1 :
        return n
    else :

         res = n*factorial(n-1)
         return res



print("Enter a number")
val = input()

factorial(val)
```

Comment: And what's the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the str type does not support the multiplier operator. If you change the following line:

```
val = input()
```

to:

```
val = int(input())
```

The factorial function works like it is supposed to.

Comment: The input is the type string. When giving the input to the function the underlying type is still string, therefore in this case you have to explicitly tell that you want the input to be of type int.